# Selenium Webdriver - Jenkins cant find Iframe

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Basic outline of the problem:

I have a selenium web-driver test that is meant to perform a signup for a new customer on a website. In order to complete the signup process i need to enter credit card data. All payment information needs to be enter in to a payment gateway that's hosted within a iframe.

Now to my problem, when running my test locally it passes with out any problems. My web-driver test is able to locate all objects.

But when try to run it on our Jenkins build server we get an error saying that Jenkins cant find the iframe:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: zuora-iframe
>   Build info: version: '2.43.0', revision: 'accb3003b9fb8f7cae30f9669b4c594a065396a6', time: '2014-09-09 22:22:51'
>   System info: host: 'JENKINS', ip: '192.168.0.112', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>       at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.switchToFrame(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous4949736922419206681webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9687:5)
>       at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous4949736922419206681webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11612:16)
>       at .fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous4949736922419206681webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:548:5)
>
> Results :
>
> Tests in error: 
>     sigupTest(se.pp.home.seleniumtest.sigupTest): Unable to locate frame: zuora-iframe(..)
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
>
> [ERROR] There are test failures.

In the test im using `driver.switchTo().frame("zuora-iframe");`to switch between the frames.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Jenkins, generally this type issue occurs due to network latency. I'll suggest to use a proper wait condition before switching into iframe.

Comment: Ok will try that out.